# PHP fwrite to null?

Tags: php, logging

My home-made simple logger (just a wrapper around `fopen`, `fwrite`, `fclose`) should be enabled or disabled on the fly. I think the way i'm checking if logging is enable is **overkill** (every call to a logging method requires to evaluate `LOGGING`):

**config.inc.php**

```
define('LOGGING', true);
```

**logger.php**

```
public function __construct($filename)
{
    $this->fp = fopen($filename, 'w+');
}

public function __destruct()
{
    fclose($this->fp);
}

public function warn($message)
{
   $this->log('WARN', $message);
}

private function log($type, $message)
{
   if(!defined(LOGGING) || !LOGGING) return;

   fwrite($this->fp, "[$type] $message\n");
}
```

Question: **how to initialize file handler to something like `null`** and remove the check for `LOGGING`? I mean something like this:

```
public function __construct($filename)
{
   // Create a fake stream if logging is disabled
   $this->fp = !defined(LOGGING) || !LOGGING ? null : fopen($filename, 'w+);
}
```

Future call to `$logger->warn('Ops..')` should do nothing, without triggering any error or notice.

Comment: Actually, yeah it's only specific to Unix-like OSes.

Comment: Ops... i don't know the production OS...

Comment: Suggest to create a special `Null`-Logger, that just doesn't anything when called. In environments, where you don't want to log use this logger-class.

Comment: @KingCrunch what do you think of `php://output`?

Comment: @Gremo: That causes PHP to output your log messages to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned it as a comment above. However, now once again as an answer, because now I think it is one.

You can create a special logger subclass, something like

```
class NullLogger implements Logger {
  public function log ($message) { /* No operation */ }
}
```

When `LOGGING` is `false`, just use this log class and every call with just doing nothing, what will reduce the overhead to the absolute minimum.

This approach has even an own name/pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern

Comment: +1 I just remembered that I have a `Logger_Disabled` subclass in my homebrew framework. Additionally, for what it's worth, it doesn't matter in terms of polymorphism whether `Logger` is an interface or a class - in my case it was an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend this class and override the log method (leave empty body for example). Then if logging is disabled, create object of child class.

Answer (score 0):

The overhead of file operations is going to VASTLY outweight the overhead of doing `if (LOGGING) { ... }`. You're optimizing the entirely wrong thing. Checking if `LOGGING` is true is a simple single value comparison. By comparison, a file operation, even if you're writing to /dev/null, requires invoking file system operations, OS buffers, permissions checks, blah blah blah.

I don't know about you, but I'll do the operation that costs $0.01 each versus one that has the same effect but costs $100 each time.